# Plotting with known final value

Tags: plotting

I want to make a plot with a condition in such a way that the function `A3` is zero at above some value of argument `x`.

For example, in the following equation, I need `A3[9] = 0` and for `x > 9`. 
I also want the plot of the function to go to zero at value `x = 9`. 
How I can do that?

```
A3[x_] := 
  10/(2.0816*x) (SphericalBesselJ[1, 2.0816*x/
         10]*(-10/(2*2.0816 x) SphericalBesselJ[1, 2.0816*x/10] + 
        1/2 (SphericalBesselJ[0, 2.08*x/10] - 
             SphericalBesselJ[2, 2.0816*x/10]))*(Sin[Pi/6])^2) +
             (SphericalBesselJ[1, 2.0816*x/10])^2*(Cos[Pi/6])^2/((2.0816*x)/10)^2;

Plot[{A3[x]}, {x, -20, 20}, AxesLabel -> {x, z}]
```

Comment: `A3[x + 7.36521]` will have a first zero for $x$ very close to $9$. I found that value using `FindRoot[A3[9 + i] == 0, {i, 7.3}]`.

Comment: Is `A3` the same thing as `A`?  What are we allowed to adjust in your equation for `A3` to make `A3[9] = 0`?  If the function `A3` is what you've shown here, then its value at 9 is completely defined.

Comment: Hi yes. it's A3[9]=0. Yes, the value at A3[9]=0 is defined, as its the boundary of the sphere in a problem I am trying to solve or we can say that x=R=9 is the radius of the sphere so outside sphere A3[R]=0

Comment: You can use `Boole` with some condition to restrict `A3` being non-zero in some range: `A3[x] Boole[x<=9]`.

Comment: If you want to just show you plot inside sphere, you can do this like: `Plot[A3[x]*Boole[-9<x<9],{x,-20,20}, AxesLabel->{x,z}]`, or better re-formulate and re-solve your problem so that the solution automatically goes to 0 at the sphere's radius.

Comment: Actually, its spin texture which does not exist outside the sphere. It's in spherical co-ordinate, I get A3[R]=0 when Theta=Pi/2 but it will be zero at Rsin(theta) when theta not equal Pi/2.

Comment: @physicsu83, is that what you need? `Plot[Piecewise[{{A3[x], x < 9}, {0, x >= 9}}], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: Yes exactly...Thank you very much.